# When editing two comments, after having saved the first edit, it is impossible to save the second edit

Tags: bug, editing, comments

I have encountered a bug in the site [*Super User*](http://www.superuser.com).

I make two comments :

1. Here is the Tadpole.
2. There is the Caterpillar.

To edit the comment 1, I click *edit*. In editing my comment, I add my new text :
*The Tadpole becomes the Frog.*

To edit the comment 2, I click *edit*. In editing my comment, I add my new text :
*The Caterpillar becomes the Butterfly.*

For the comment 1, I click *Save Edits*. This works.

For the comment 2, I click *Save Edits*. This has to work. But this does not work.

I have Firefox 28 on Mac.

I will reproduce the bug here.

Thank you for fixing this little bug, and keep up the good work !

Comment: Here is a Tadpole. The Tadpole becomes the Frog.

Comment: There is the Caterpillar.